# Get outgoing transactions from Solana account

Tags: transactions, rpc

Is there some RPC call/efficient way of getting only the outgoing transactions from a Solana account? By "outgoing" I mean that the account actually signed the tx, i.e. that it wasn't e.g. a tx where the account was included just as a destination.

I know there is the [getsignaturesforaddress](https://solana.com/docs/rpc/http/getsignaturesforaddress) RPC call, however that one seems to return all transactions related to given Solana account, regardless of whether they were signed by given account or not, so it doesn't really seem suitable to me in terms of efficiency

Answer (score 1):

You're correct about `getSignaturesForAddress`, and I'm not aware of any RPC call that does what you're looking for. I think you'd need to use an indexer that can provide this.

One option would be [Helius' parsed transaction history API](https://docs.helius.dev/solana-apis/enhanced-transactions-api/parsed-transaction-history). Another would be [Shyft's Account Transaction History API](https://docs.shyft.to/solana-apis/transactions/transaction-apis#get-transaction-history). Both return the fee payer as a field (Shyft also returns all signers) for each transaction returned so you could easily identify those you need.